# Glass 5.8 language fallback seems to be working differently to 5.4

Tags: glass-mapper

We’ve *upgraded* from Sitecore `9.02` to `10.3` and also `GlassMapper` to `5.8`. We have a strange situation, where in `Glass 5.4/Sitecore 9.02` *if there is no specific version of an item for a language it would return the English version*.

However this does **not** seem to happen now after upgrading. A `null` model is returned instead.

Also when editing in experience editor it used to prompt to enter data (by showing *[no value in field]* - and create an English language version on save) if there was no English version of an item. But now, it just throw a model error instead.

`MvcContext.GetDataSourceItem< T >()` is the method we’re using in our controllers for example.

Has the code changed to handle this differently between versions? I’ve checked but struggling to see anything. Or am I missing some Glass/Sitecore config or something? as I’ve checked and the config seems to be the same...

Comment: I don't think that's related to Glass Mapper. As far as I know, there is no word "fallback" in Glass Mapper source code. That would have to be a change in Sitecore itself. Have you tried using oout Sitecore Field() instead of Glass and see if you notice same issue?

Comment: Hey @MarekMusielak I've spent quite a while looking at the GlassMapper source code for 5.8 and couldn't really see anything either. I've not got any pages setup with just vanilla Sitecore API field rendering but I will see if I can set one up to test this. Good idea.